# How do I clear the text of a text control dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table of rows and each row has an edit button. When I click the button I can set row values to form controls on a form.

I'm expecting that when I call `$('#txtFirstName').empty()` it should clear the text in `txtFirstName`. Instead, the text is not cleared, and when I call the form again it shows the old text in that control.

Is there a way to clear text in the control?

```
$('#btnClear').click(function () {
    $('#txtFirstName').empty();
    $('#txtLastName').empty();
}
```

The source code shows as data was cleared.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="employee_FirstName">First Name</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The First Name field is required." id="txtFirstName" name="employee.FirstName" placeholder="First Name" style="width:400px" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="employee.FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="employee_LastName">Last Name</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Last Name field is required." id="txtLastName" name="employee.LastName" placeholder="Last Name" style="width:400px" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="employee.LastName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This information might be coming from the cache, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `.val('')` - http://api.jquery.com/val

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i did that too, but it shows the text. the form has a close button and in the click event i have written the code to clear the text field but the problem still exists !

Comment: @PhillGreggan: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ys2746cg/  Maybe you could show the actual code you're using that isn't working as expected?

Comment: I guess that you have multiple inputs with the same `id` when the `id` should be unique in the same document, if this is the case replace `id='txtFirstName'` by `class='txtFirstName'`.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki there are multiples inputs but different Ids. the form is html (MVC razor) when i close the form it should clear text associated with textboxes but it does not, when the forms shows again it shows with the previous text.... even in the html it shows values are cleared but how come it get data from cache?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki and you have marked my topic as off-topic, isn't this clearing input dynamically?

Comment: You should add more details and concerned parts in your code to the OP, since from your description it's should work like the other comments mentioned.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki i have updated my OP with code

Comment: Try to add an alert inside the click event to make sure that the event is achieved.

Comment: @PhillGreggan: `empty()` doesn't do what you think it does.  The first comment on this question is your answer: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhz3bs86/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@RoryMcCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan) said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34724182#comment57194148_34724182) above, what you're looking for is [`jQuery.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

> Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.

[`jQuery.empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) does not do what you think it should.

> Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM

Because you are trying to change the value of an element, instead of removing elements from the DOM, you should use [`jQuery.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

As a side note, you have a syntax error in your JavaScript above. You are missing a closing parenthesis `)` at the end of the argument list of `$('#btnClear').click`. Whether that was a copy and paste error or not, I thought I would point it out.

Also note that instead of applying [`jQuery.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to each element you want to clear, you can select the elements by class and apply [`jQuery.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to the returned jQuery object, which will apply the operation to every element with the matching class.

Here's a simple example:

```js
$('#clear').click(function() {
    $('.form-control').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<input class="form-control">
<input class="form-control">
<input class="form-control">
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```